# Jupiter Notebook, When I call a stored procedure on sql server using Python

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

Jupiter Notebook, I am debugging a Jupiter notebook that locks up a sql server.  Running the notebook causes locks.

When a notebook calls a procedure or does inserts updates, ect.  Does Python wait until the proc is finished to move to the next cell?  or just it just go on to the next cell after the call?

The notebook I inherited does tons of ddl commands that are dependent on previous steps.

How can I check and control?

Comment: Unless you've introduced asynchronous logic into your python, it's going to wait for the previous step to complete before moving on, just like any other line of code. At any rate, it's hard to understand your question fully without seeing your code.

Comment: What SQL server and what engine are you using?